# JSON string return which contain Javascript and HTML by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have issue to create JSON response of my RESTFul API. Following javascript code need to send as JSON response :

```
<script language="JavaScript">var zflag_nid="3372"; var zflag_cid="2/1"; var zflag_sid="1"; var zflag_width="300"; var zflag_height="250"; var zflag_msize="1366x768:9,728x90:19,310x352:19";        </script><script language="JavaScript" src="http://xp2.xyz.com/jsc/xp2/fo.js"></script>
```

And my code snippet is :

```
$str = '<script language="JavaScript">var zflag_nid="3372"; var zflag_cid="2/1"; var zflag_sid="1"; var zflag_width="300"; var zflag_height="250"; var zflag_msize="1366x768:9,728x90:19,310x352:19";                 </script><script language="JavaScript" src="http://xp2.xyz.com/jsc/xp2/fo.js"></script>';
        //echo $str;
        echo json_encode(array("data"=>$str,"msg"=>"success","status"=>200));
```

I am getting wrong JSON output response by above manner.
Please help me to get correct JSON response.

My response is  :

```
{"data":"
<script language=\"JavaScript\">var zflag_nid=\"3372\"; var zflag_cid=\"2\/1\"; var zflag_sid=\"1\"; var zflag_width=\"300\"; var zflag_height=\"250\"; var zflag_msize=\"1366x768:9,728x90:19,310x352:19\";<\/script>
    <script language=\"JavaScript\" src=\"http:\/\/xp2.xyz.com\/jsc\/xp2\/fo.js\"><\/script>","msg":"success","status":200}
```

Comment: Show us what you get and what you expect to get. _"I'm getting wrong JSON"_ isn't a good enough error description for us to have any clue what your issue is.

Comment: Following Response I am getting : {"data":"
<script language=\"JavaScript\">var zflag_nid=\"3372\"; var zflag_cid=\"2\/1\"; var zflag_sid=\"1\"; var zflag_width=\"300\"; var zflag_height=\"250\"; var zflag_msize=\"1366x768:9,728x90:19,310x352:19\";<\/script>
    <script language=\"JavaScript\" src=\"http:\/\/xp2.zedo.com\/jsc\/xp2\/fo.js\"><\/script>","msg":"success","status":200}

Comment: Edit your question with all the info instead of posting code/data in a comment. It's pretty unreadable in comments.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I added response code in question itself, kindly check once again.

Comment: So you are talking about "\"s in response?

Comment: What's wrong with the response? Looks right to me.

Comment: Except from the line breaks (that I'm guessing that you've added yourself and makes the json invalid), it looks like valid json. Line breaks inside the content is a no no. They need to be escaped as: `\n`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thats surprizing for me too. Line breaks coming. Its pretty simple but still getting wrong JSON response.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/pYKgS - Your code is working. You must be doing something else. `json_encode()` doesn't generate invalid json. How would it even know to add the line breaks right before the `<script..`-tags? How are How are you copying the generated json? Browser? Do you have any browser plugin that's formatting the output?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I just update phpfiddle link please what response I am getting.

Comment: Are you joking? Go troll somewhere else, please.